# read a unsigned int from stdin via fread

Tags: c, stdin, fread, unsigned-integer

I did not write this code, but I would like to use it and understand exactly what it is doing.

```
unsigned int j;
if (fread(&j,sizeof(unsigned int),1,stdin) != 1) {
  if (feof(stdin)) {
    fprintf(stderr,"# stdin_input_raw(): Error: EOF\n");
  } else {
    fprintf(stderr,"# stdin_input_raw(): Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
  }
  exit(0);
}
printf("raw: %10u\n",j); 
return j;
```

I do know that the code is reading unisgned integers from the stdin, but in my tests the output `j` isnt the integer I wrote into the stdin by hand.

So I would like to know what the code is doing and how I may change it to return the correct input.

Ps: I am using Visual Studio C, not C++ on a Windows machine.

Comment: Of course it's not what you've typed: you are reading the data in binary mode.

Comment: so can you give me a hint how i can validate the correctness of the input ? is it just the number i typed in in binary form ?

Comment: No, it's the bytes of the ASCII characters representing the number that you have typed. For example, if you typed `1234`, your program will see `0x31323334` - the codes of characters `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, and `'4'`.

Comment: Thank you very much.
But the Output is neither 0x31323334 nor the decimal of this
825373492. the outcome is 875770417. can you explain me why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation points to reply to your comment on your question but the reason you get "875770417" instead of "825373492" when you type 1234 is the following:

`875770417(dec) = 0x34333231`

`825373492(dec) = 0x31323334`

If you look closely you will see that the bytes in the hex values are backwards (each two characters in the hex is a byte). This is because you are on a little endian machine. The bytes were written to stdin as '1' '2' '3' '4'. This is how a little endian machine would write 875770417 to memory, and when it reads the same sequence into a register it will get that integer, not the one you assumed was correct.

As a note little endian means you write the least-significant bytes to the lowest address memory locations so `0x1A2A3A4A` would be layed out as `|4A|3A|2A|1A|`, where left is lowest address and right is the highest address. In your example you had `|31|32|33|34` in memory so you read in `0x34333231`

Answer (score 0):

In what way doesn't it work?

I would suggest that using an `unsigned int` is perhaps not the best thing to do if you want the data to be portable, as the size of an `int` is not fixed; something like a `uint32_t` may be better suited.

Similarly, the code as written assumes the byte-order of the data is the same as the host.

Also, replacing `sizeof(unsigned int)` with `sizeof j` would lead to fewer bugs.

If it is failing, then a hexdump of the input data, and the output of the program would be useful.

To form a test input, you could use something like Perl's `pack` function.

It would be instructive to experiment with this on something like a 32-bit, 64-bit machine, and on a x86 (little endian), and ppc (big endian).